# Getting the value or index of Combobox item?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am trying to make my GUI display information depending on the item chosen in the combobox. `PySimpleGUI` cookbook says that I should be using `GetSelectedItemsIndexes()` method, but when I try using it:

```
window.Element('_COMBOBOX_').GetSelectedItemsIndexes()
```

I get this:

> AttributeError: 'Combo' object has no attribute 'GetSelectedItemsIndexes'

I tried type this into the console:

```
dir(window.Element('_COMBOBOX_'))
```

and it seems that `GetSelectedItemsIndexes` is not even there... So how can I get the index of a chosen value from combobox?

Comment: The solution I found is to take the selected value from `value` list using the `key` of combobox :)

Comment: This is exactly the right way of getting the value.  You do not need to make a call as ALL of the window's input values are returned to you when you call `window.Read()`.  In fact, the function GetSelectedItemsIndexes is no longer available.

Answer (score 6):

This work for me:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Combo(['choice 1', 'choice 2', 'choice 3'], enable_events=True, key='combo')],
          [sg.Button('Test'), sg.Exit()]
          ]

window = sg.Window('combo test', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if event == 'Test':
        combo = values['combo']  # use the combo key
        print(combo)

window.Close()
```

Comment: You can also directly access the value by writing `values['combo']`

Comment: Oh, that is more simple. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The examples in the documentation and all of the demo programs use the `values['key']` style lookups (that's as you pointed out, more simple).  You may want to edit your answer to more closely match the designs of typical PySimpleGUI programs.